# SQLite sqlite3_prepare_v2 no error but not ok neither

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite, ios4

Hey guys, I'm just playing around with SQLite so this is new for me. I've got a view in which persons data can be both saved and found. The save-function and find-function work perfectly. Now, I've got a new view with a tableView in it. I want to get all the persons in the contacts-table and fill the list with it.

Untill now, I've got:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Opened DB");
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name FROM contacts"];

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        NSLog(@"could not prepare statement: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        //if (sqlite3_step(query_stmt) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            //NSLog(@"SQLite OK");
            NSLog(@"SQLite ok");
            //if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            //{
                while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                    NSLog(@"SQLite ROW");
                    NSString *person = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                    [personsList addObject:person];
                }
            //} else {
            //    NSLog(@"Emtpy list");
            //}
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
    NSLog(@"Calling reload");
    NSLog(@"%@", personsList);
    [tabelView reloadData];
}
```

This is all in viewWillAppear. When the view is loaded and done, the log says:
`2011-05-06 10:45:26.976 database[1412:207] Opened DB`

`2011-05-06 10:45:26.978 database[1412:207] could not prepare statement: not an error`

`2011-05-06 10:45:26.979 database[1412:207] Calling reload`

`2011-05-06 10:45:26.979 database[1412:207] (`

`)`

So it seems the statement isn't an error, but `sqlite3_prepare_v2` isn't SQL_OK after all. Any help?

EDIT: In the previous view, the statement for creating a person is: `@"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name, address, phone) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", name.text, address.text, phone.text];`

The statement for finding someone is: `@"SELECT address, phone FROM contacts WHERE name=\"%@\"", name.text];`

These two statements work and the data is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];`, but I forgot to put the following code above it:

```
// Get the documents directory
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"contacts.db"]];
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
```

Answer (score 3):

@joetjah I used your code to fetch the results and it worked fine

```
2011-05-06 16:03:00.076 SQLiteDemo[6454:207] Opened DB
2011-05-06 16:03:09.550 SQLiteDemo[6454:207] could not prepare statement: not an error
2011-05-06 16:03:24.685 SQLiteDemo[6454:207] SQLite ok
2011-05-06 16:03:26.229 SQLiteDemo[6454:207] SQLite ROW
2011-05-06 16:03:28.254 SQLiteDemo[6454:207] SQLite ROW
2011-05-06 16:03:34.461 SQLiteDemo[6454:207] Calling reload
2011-05-06 16:03:35.009 SQLiteDemo[6454:207] (
    rahul,
    sqlite
)


-(void)testFunction{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    sqlite3 *contactDB;
    NSMutableArray *personsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc ] initWithCapacity:0];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Opened DB");
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name FROM contacts"];

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        NSLog(@"could not prepare statement: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            //if (sqlite3_step(query_stmt) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            //NSLog(@"SQLite OK");
            NSLog(@"SQLite ok");
            //if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            //{
            while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSLog(@"SQLite ROW");
                NSString *person = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                [personsList addObject:person];
            }
            //} else {
            //    NSLog(@"Emtpy list");
            //}
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
    NSLog(@"Calling reload");
    NSLog(@"%@", personsList);
    //[tabelView reloadData];
}
```

You can compare the code, The probable point of failure might be
1] data not being saved properly and hence nothing is fetched.
2] databasePath being set to blank (which I doubt as you get Open Db log)

The table contact is created using **"CREATE TABLE contacts (name text, age integer)"**
try this once and let me know if it works.

Comment: Hey, first of all, thanks for putting in so much effort in this! Strange that it's working with you but not here. My program doesn't think sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) is SQLITE_OK, although, the link with the database is. The SQL-sequence used in creating the db, is: `"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT)";`. The sequence to add something, is `"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name, address, phone) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", name.text, address.text, phone.text];`. Anything seems odd to u?

Comment: you can send me the code if you are comfortable with that. The Table creation is perfectly all right, however I am not sure If your create Statement with "CONTACTS" and fetch query using "contacts" will make any trouble.

Comment: Hey, it's no problem for me. It's pretty much taken over from a tutorial, I'm only expanding the result of that tutorial to see all of the contacts in a table list. The complete project in my state should be found here: http://megafileupload.com/en/file/311925/database-zip.html . In meanwhile, I'll make every name equal and case-equal.

Comment: all you need to do is to save the databasePath somewhere for later use, what i mean is when you first set up the database the you can save the database path and any subsequent call to database must use the saved database path. The databasePath is nil in listviewcontroller.

Comment: Exactly, the path goes into my appDelegate so every class can reach it:) Thanks for the additional information and all your time ^^ Whish I could give u another +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    // Override point for customization after app launch.
    // Setup some globals
    // Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contacts.db"];

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Opened DB");
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name FROM CONTACTS"];
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        NSLog(@"could not prepare statement: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"SQLite ok");
                while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                    NSLog(@"SQLite ROW");
                    NSString *person = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                    [personsList addObject:person];
                }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        else
        {
            //NSLog(@"could not prepare statement: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(statement));
        }
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
    NSLog(@"Calling reload");
    NSLog(@"%@", personsList);
    [tabelView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Hey, I've updated the question's code. `statement` was declared above the first if-statement, so the problem wasn't there :(

Comment: Hey, I've update my Ans, Please test it. If your prob is solved then you can should make this ans as a right.

Comment: I'm sorry, the problem hasn't been solved :( No difference in output or anything. And ofcourse I'll accept the answer if it helps :)

Comment: Hey, Now try my ans, I have tested it and its show me the list.

Comment: Yup, I posted that in my own answer (which you copy pasted in your own answer ;) ). At least this answer reflects the correct answer now. Thanks for taking the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

create the table in your didload functions and then add this in (assuming you have declared the other table view functions):

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell        

    var selectStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
    let selectSql = "select * from Inventory where ID = \((indexPath.row + 1))"
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(Database.database.sqliteDB, selectSql, -1, &selectStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK{
        if sqlite3_step(selectStatement) == SQLITE_ROW {

            let nameItem = sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 1)
            let price = sqlite3_column_double(selectStatement, 2)
            let quantity = sqlite3_column_int(selectStatement, 3)

            let nameString = String(cString: nameItem!)
            let priceString = String(format: "%.1f",price)
            let quantityString = String(quantity)

            cell.itemName.text = nameString
            cell.itemPrice.text = priceString
            cell.itemQuantity.text = quantityString

        }
    }

    return cell
}
```